# Use same unauthenticated identity for AWS Analytics and Cognito Sync

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, amazon-mobile-analytics

I'm developing an app which makes use of both AWS Mobile Analytics and Cognito Sync for user data. From looking at my network logs, I can see that the `AMA.Manager` for Mobile Analytics makes the same API calls as Cognito Sync to request limited temp credentials from AWS.

`AWS.config.credentials.get()`

My question is if its possible for both `new AMA.Manager()` and `new AWS.CognitoSyncManager()` to use the same unauthenticated identity which is requested initially from `AWS.config.credentials.get()`? Assuming they're both using the same Identity Pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own issue. As long as both `AMA.Manager` and `AWS.CognitoSyncManager` are initialized with the same credentials provider using a single IdentityPoolId it works fine. Example of my code below:

```
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: SHARED_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID
});

var analytics = null;
var syncClient = null;
var options = {
    appId : MOBILE_ANALYTICS_APP_ID
};

AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err) {

    if(!err){
        syncClient = new AWS.CognitoSyncManager();
        analytics = new AMA.Manager(options);
    }
});
```